# Bochner's Theorem and Universal Kernels

Tags: machine-learning, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

Bochner's theorem asserts that a shift-invariant and properly scaled continuous kernel $K(x,y) = k(x-y)$ is positive definite (and hence a reproducing kernel of some RKHS) if and only if its Fourier transform $p(w)$ is a probability distribution:
$$k(x-y) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} p(w) e^{i w^T(x-y)} dw$$
I am now wondering what this expression tells us about the universality of the corresponding RKHS. For which probability distributions $p(w)$ is the kernel $k(x-y)$ universal? Are there necessary and sufficient conditions?

Comment: Do you know the paper [https://jmlr.org/papers/volume7/micchelli06a/micchelli06a.pdf](https://jmlr.org/papers/volume7/micchelli06a/micchelli06a.pdf)?

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write this [continuous positive definite kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_kernel?msclkid=d065f901cf3b11eca3772c4e936d4ac8) as $$k(x-y) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} p(w) e^{i w^T(x-y)} dw = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}  e^{i w^T(x-y)} d\mu(w),$$ in which $$\mu(A)=\int_{A} p(w) dw,$$ to each measurable set $A\subset \mathbb{R}^d$, and $\rho:\mathbb{R}^d\to [0,\infty)$ is a measurable function.

If $\rho\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and $supp(\mu)$ has positive Lebesgue measure then Theorem 15 of https://jmlr.org/papers/volume7/micchelli06a/micchelli06a.pdf tell us that $K$ is a universal kernel.

Please see also Theorem 3.7 in https://doi.org/10.1007/s11117-016-0414-4 to density in $C_0(\mathbb{R}^d)$.

You can find some related result searching for "[\( K(x,y)=f(x-y)\)  universal kernel](https://www.searchonmath.com/arxiv/result?q=%5C%28%20K%28x,y%29%3Df%28x-y%29%5C%29%20%20universal%20kernel%20)" on SearchOnMath, for instance.

Comment: Thanks again, I have to admit this is surprising to me. Is $\lambda(supp(\mu))>0$ also a necessary condition? What happens if $supp(\mu)$ has zero measure?

Comment: This is a good question, and I do not know a general answer. You can ask something also when $\rho\not\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$. Note that $K(x-y)=\cos(f(x)-f(y))=cos(f(x))\cos(f(y))+\sin(f(x))\sin(f(y))$ is not a universal kernel, because it is not strictly pd.

Comment: This text is also related to your question [https://arxiv.org/pdf/1003.0887.pdf](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1003.0887.pdf)

Comment: Quick thought, if $p(w) \in L^1$ but vanishes almost everywhere, then the kernel is zero, right? So it will not be universal

Comment: Yes because it is continuous.

Comment: So for continuous tranlsation invariant positive definite kernels $\lambda(supp(\mu))>0$ is not only sufficient but also necessary for universality?

Comment: I agree, when $\rho\in L^1$.